# Conditionally show content in AngularJS templates using ternary operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display a button depending on the result of ternary operator in Angular JS, but I am not able to display the HTML content inside the curly braces, it only allows the string form. Below is my code.

```
{{x.status === "pending" ? "pending" : "Card is Already Verified"}}
<ons-button ng-click="setCard(x); page.pushPage('verifyCard.html', {animation: 'slide'});">Verify <ons-icon icon="ion-checkmark"></ons-button>
```

If the status is pending, I want to display the ons-button in pending field.

Comment: you can use ng-show ='x.status==="pending"' in ons-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
<ons-button ng-show='x.status === "pending"' ng-click="setCard(x); page.pushPage('verifyCard.html', {animation: 'slide'});">Verify <ons-icon icon="ion-checkmark"></ons-button>
```

ng-show documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` directive to show/hide the button. For example

```
<ons-button ng-show="condition">
```

In place of condition you need to place the valid condtion. If that condition is true then the button will be shown, else button will be hidden.